# Stripe - action on charge succeeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I've just started using Stripe and have followed their guide on setting up a [checkout with Rails](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails)

In my case, i'm giving users to ability to upgrade an event listing.

In my event model I have a make_premium method:

```
  def make_premium
    self.update_attribute(:premium_event, true)
  end
```

My event_controller's upgrade action is on Based on Stripe's create example, except i've added a repond_to block to take users back to the event they upgraded and also call the make_premium method.

```
  def upgrade
    @event = Event.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    # Amount in pence
    @amount = 299

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => current_user.email,
      :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Premium Event Upgrade',
      :currency    => 'gbp',
      :metadata => {'event_id' => @event.id, 'event_headline' => @event.headline}
    )

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to @event, :notice => 'Event was successfully upgraded.' }
       @event.make_premium
    end

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
  end
```

What I want to know, is a) is the respond to block ok to use here given the rescue that comes after and b) is it ok to call my make_premium method from within this block?

I've played around with using Stripe's webhooks and while the charge.suceeded hook works well, it seems like an extra step I could avoid if the above is sufficient.

Any insight from people more experienced with Stripe would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost positive that you can have a `rescue` block anywhere in a method and it will get called if the exception occurs.

The only potential change I would suggest is to add a check to make sure the attribute got updated successfully.

```
def upgrade
    @event = Event.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    # Amount in pence
    @amount = 299

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => current_user.email,
      :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Premium Event Upgrade',
      :currency    => 'gbp',
      :metadata => {'event_id' => @event.id, 'event_headline' => @event.headline}
    )

    respond_to do |format|
       if @event.make_premium
         format.html { redirect_to @event, :notice => 'Event was successfully upgraded.' }
       else
         // handle error and redirect
       end
    end

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
  end
```

Comment: Ok great, that makes sense. I'll add that in. Thanks